# Objective C: How does 7 - 1 = 3?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, math, pointers

```
NSLog(@"Before: %d",currentArticle);
currentArticle--;
NSLog(@"SUBTRACT %d",currentArticle);
```

"currentArticle" is an integer. This is only being echoed once in my console. If I do not run this subtraction, the number "currentArticle" remains at 7.

This is being run in the main thread, and only run once per user interaction.

I have also tried

```
currentArticle = currentArticle - 1;
```

With the same result. Am I taking crazy pills?

Thanks!

Edit:

Declared as follows:

```
extern int *currentArticle;
```

And assigned later as:

```
currentArticle = 0;
```

---

I tried rewriting as this:

```
int *curArticle; // in my .h file

curArticle = 1;
```

And then I run the

```
curArticle--;
```

and it still decrements by two...

I have stepped through the code and ensured there are no other calls hitting this variable.. Thanks for the feedback so far, I will keep hacking away at it.

Comment: Are you sure it is an integer and not a pointer which happens to contain an integer?

Comment: Show the place where you declare currentArticle.

Comment: I don't believe that `currentArticle` is an integer.

Comment: __Does it always add up to 3? What if you restart the process or the machine?__ (if it's a pointer to something, then changing the environment might well change the location of the pointer and what's in it - giving you a different result.)

Comment: @cartoonfox the problem is that he's using a `int*` as if it was an `int`, so he's setting the pointer to 7 (not what the pointer points to) and then decrementing by 1 `int`, i.e. 4 bytes, getting the address 3. So changing the environment won't change anything unless he moves to an environment where sizeof(int) != 4 bytes.

Comment: @OP why do you need that to be a pointer? can't you just use a `extern int currentArticle`? If you have a reason to use a pointer there, you have to derreference it (`*curArticle = 1;`) to set or read the value it's pointing to (assuming you set the pointer to point to an actual `int` somewhere)

Comment: @filipe - d'oh! Next time I'll try reading the question & answers properly. Thanks for clarifying things though. Sorry!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I concur with the comments above. I'd bet a dollar that your code looks like:

```
int *currentArticle = 7; // or something
```

currentArticle may not even be a pointer to an int, specifically, but it's very likely a pointer to some 4-byte type. The '--' and '++' operators, when applied to pointers, decrement or increment by the size of the type that's pointed to.

Comment: Probably not `int` explicitly - the ever-not-what-it-seems `NSInteger`, perhaps? (Which is an `int` under the hood)

Comment: As I mentioned, it's likely a pointer to some type whose size is 4 bytes. I used 'int *' as an example because the OP said 'integer', but it could really be a pointer to any type whose size is 4.

Comment: @John -- there you go. If you change it from 'extern int *' to 'extern int' you'll surely have better luck. (The "*" means "this is a pointer.")

Comment: The reason several people all came to the same conclusion is that, well, everyone learns this lesson the hard way. Keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

Things I think of: Threads (if it's a strange problem, there are threads)? Or is it called by an event (which is triggered more than once)?