# Problem add up Integer xCode

Tags: c, pointers, int

I have this irritating problem, and I can't find the answer for it. 
For a reason my integers are binary, instead of decimal.

It's just this little part and when I print my integer I get: 
0
4
8
12
16
...

The code I use:

```
    int *iInt=0;
for (Books *booktitles in appDelegate.book_sos.books ) {
    iInt =(int*)iInt + 1;
    NSLog(@"AAAAAAA%d",iInt);

}
```

I tried it with NSNumber, NSInteger .

Does someone knows where I could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C: How does 7 - 1 = 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267187/objective-c-how-does-7-1-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lose the asterisk from your declaration of iInt, and don't cast to `int*`. The asterisk means that the variable is a pointer to the given type, and when you increment a pointer it increases by the size of the pointer, or 4 bytes in this case. Your code should look like this:

```
int iInt=0;
for (Books *booktitles in appDelegate.book_sos.books ) {
    iInt =(int)iInt + 1;
    NSLog(@"AAAAAAA%d",iInt);

}
```

See [Objective-C: How does 7-1=3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267187/objective-c-how-does-7-1-3/5267239#5267239) for another version of the same question.

Note that this is a basic C question; it has nothing to do with Xcode or Objective-C. You'd get a similar result with any C compiler on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a pointer TO AN `int`, not an `int`. Don't do that.

```
int iInt=0;
for (Books *booktitles in appDelegate.book_sos.books ) {
    iInt = iInt + 1;
    NSLog(@"AAAAAAA%d",iInt);
}
```